# Laravel one to many relation with a one to one relation

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I may be going about this wrong but i need a model to have a one to many and a one to one relation.

I have the following tables:

- `bots`
- `bot_settings`
- `message`
- `section`

I have the following relations:

- `Bot` belong to a `Section` (one to many)
- `BotSettings` belong to a `Bot` (one to one)
- `ArMessage` belong to a `Section` (one to many)

All of this is working as expected the one im having a problem with:

- `ArMessage` also have a one to one relation with the `BotSettings`

Aa i already have them belonging to a section im not sure how i can also link them to a BotSetttings i think i may need to alter my relations but not sure how.

Iv read the docs and tried everything from there not sure what to try now.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You must be joking,you have already done that,with other tables

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship for connecting one to all the others.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\BotSettings',
            'App\Section',
            'bot_settings_id', // Foreign key on BotSettings table...
            'section_id', // Foreign key on Sections table...
            'id', // Local key on BotSettings table...
            'id' // Local key on Sections table...
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this type of method for one to one or one to many

```
public function yourmethod(){
    return Modalnamewhereyouwanttoretrive::where('yourcolmn',$this->foreign_key)->get(); 
}
```